# Does Pavement ME Design output the tensile strain beneath an AC layer?

Tags: pavement

I'd like to know the tensile strain beneath the asphalt concrete (AC) layer in my design structure. Usually, the strain is used to calculate the number of axles (Nf) that the pavement structure can take before failure. Do you know how/where I can find that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tensile strain beneath the AC layer is not an output in Pavement ME Design due to the vast number of calculations performed within the Asphalt Pavement Design System (APADS) analysis module.

The size of the output file is too large to output (3 – 10gb or more). The reason for the large file size is due to the analysis being performed for each month, sub-month, sub-seasons, vertical locations, all axle configurations, axle load spectra’s for each axle configuration, and all traffic wander locations.

The “.fat” intermediate output file summarizes the monthly fatigue damage for the vertical depth and wander locations. The maximum fatigue damage value between all wander locations for the last vertical depth location is used for the bottom-up fatigue cracking calculations.